# Pandas crosstab giving error unstack() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a crosstab running the following:

```py
import pandas as pd 
from seaborn import load_dataset

dfx = load_dataset("tips")

pd.crosstab(dfx['time'], dfx['day'])
```

When I run the code, I get this:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[196], line 1
    pd.crosstab(dfx['time'], dfx['day'])

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py:711 in crosstab

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:9193 in pivot_table
    Difference with following row

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py:99 in pivot_table
    values,

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py:189 in __internal_pivot_table
    v in data

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:9625 in unstack
    Note that a vectorized version of `func` often exists, which will

TypeError: unstack() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code is running well, so please check it carefully and ask again.

Comment: I've run it several  times with different data frames and get the same result.  Could it be a version issue?  The version I have is 1.5.3.

Comment: I also use 1.5.3. This is not a version issue. you can chk that it is not version issue by running it in Google Colab(1.5.3). Also, there is no reason why the error message should include `unstack`, as there is no `unstack` in the code you provided. This situation usually occurs when a newbie provides different code from the code they actually ran and tries to find the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the possible cause of your problem; try this:

```
pd.crosstab(dfx['time'], [dfx['day']])
```

The second argument may be the cause.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it.  I updated Pandas and that seems to have fixed my issue.  However, if I run into this issue again, I'll give it a try.